# Performance of non-clustered indexes on different column types

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, indexing

Is a non-clustered index on an `int` column considered more performant than one on a `decimal` or `datetime` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some ways: yes.

An `INT` is only 4 bytes - so more `INT`s will fit on a single 8K page in SQL Server.

`DATETIME` uses 8 bytes - so fewer `DATETIME` values are store on a single page, or for the same number of `DATETIME`s, you need more pages, hence you get more disk I/O and thus less performance.

How **much** of a difference there is, is up to more detailed measurement, however - for anything under millions of rows, the difference most likely will be negligable. If your queries do benefit from an index on that `DATETIME` column - I wouldn't hesitate adding it (again: unless you're dealing with multi-million row tables... then you might need more detailed investigations)

Comment: Also many people overlook SMALLDATETIME - which is the same width as an INT and can be a suitable replacement for DATETIME if sub-minute accuracy is not important (it often isn't).